# Build more efficient MS SQL function to return evenly split ranges

Tags: sql-server, sql-function, sql-optimization

Say you have following SQL table:

```
-- create temp table
CREATE TABLE [tempNums] 
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    somedate datetime NULL
)
GO
```

With some data (see below for tempSplitStringToInts definition):

```
-- with date
INSERT INTO [tempNums]
    SELECT id, GETUTCDATE()
    FROM [tempSplitStringToInts] ('1,2,3,5,10,100,101,102,103,233,1001,5002,5003,5005,5007,5010',',') 
GO

-- without date
INSERT INTO [tempNums]
    SELECT id, NULL
    FROM [tempSplitStringToInts] ('6,7,8,150,151,152,153,433,2001,2002,2003,2005,3007,10010',',') 
GO
```

> How do you build BETTER/FASTER function that will take number of ranges, and a
>   flag bit as input and return a table of range values?

Something like this works for example, but is slow for very large tables:

```
-- create range function
CREATE FUNCTION [tempFnGetIdRanges]
(
    @apps INT,
    @has_date BIT
)
RETURNS @ret TABLE
(
    RangeNum INT, 
    MinNum INT, 
    MaxNum INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @i INT = 0;
    DECLARE @count INT;
    DECLARE @min INT;
    DECLARE @max INT = 0;

    IF @has_date = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT @count = COUNT(id) 
            FROM [tempNums] 
            WHERE somedate IS NOT NULL
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @count = COUNT(id) 
            FROM [tempNums] 
            WHERE somedate IS NULL

    END

    DECLARE @top INT = @count/@apps;

    WHILE @i<@apps
    BEGIN

        IF @i+1=@apps
        BEGIN
            -- on last get reminder
            SET @top = @top + @apps 
        END

        IF @has_date = 1
        BEGIN       
            SELECT @min = MIN(id), @max = MAX(id)
            FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP (@top) id 
                FROM [tempNums] 
                WHERE somedate IS NOT NULL
                    AND id > @max
                ORDER BY id
            ) XX
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @min = MIN(id), @max = MAX(id)
            FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP (@top) id 
                FROM [tempNums] 
                WHERE somedate IS NULL
                    AND id > @max
                ORDER BY id
            ) XX
        END


        INSERT INTO @ret VALUES(@i, @min, @max)

        SET @i = @i + 1;
        CONTINUE
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```

So when you run following:

```
SELECT * FROM [tempFnGetIdRanges](4, 0)
SELECT * FROM [tempFnGetIdRanges](4, 1)
```

Result for first statement:

```
RangeNum    MinNum  MaxNum
0           6       8
1           150     152
2           153     2001
3           2002    10010
```

Result for second statement:

```
RangeNum    MinNum  MaxNum
0           1       5
1           10      102
2           103     5002
3           5003    5010
```

Split function (for reference, but not the point of this question):

```
-- create split string function
CREATE  FUNCTION [tempSplitStringToInts] ( @SourceString VARCHAR(MAX) , @delimeter VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS @IntList TABLE
   (
     id INT
   )
AS
BEGIN
IF RIGHT(@SourceString, LEN(@delimeter))<> @delimeter
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SourceString = @SourceString + @delimeter
    END

DECLARE @LocalStr VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @start INT
DECLARE @end INT
SELECT @start = 1
SELECT @end =  CHARINDEX ( @delimeter , @SourceString , @start ) 

WHILE @end > 0
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @LocalStr = SUBSTRING ( @SourceString , @start , @end - @start ) 
        IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@LocalStr)) <> '' 
            BEGIN
                INSERT @IntList (id) VALUES (CAST(@LocalStr AS INT))
            END
        SELECT @start = @end + LEN(@delimeter)
        SELECT @end = CHARINDEX ( @delimeter , @SourceString , @start ) 
    END
   RETURN
END
GO
```

> As I said this works, but it is slow for very large tables. Is there a
>   better way to write `tempFnGetIdRanges` function? Something native to
>   SQL? I am using `MS SQL 2012` if that is relevant.

Comment: You have some definite performance challenges here. First, you are creating table valued functions but they are multi-statement table valued functions which are almost always slower than even a scalar function. For the performance benefit of a table valued function is must be a single select statement and nothing more. I would start by trashing that splitter you have. It is the the worst of the worst. It has a loop inside a table valued function. Here are some better choices for that. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Great, thanks for the comment. I'll look at better splitter functions.

Comment: What is that main function doing? When HasDate = 1 it is just splitting them into groups, but when it is null the output doesn't make any sense to me. What is the logic there?

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples of using `for xml` to split strings. I benchmarked them, and they are increasingly faster with the increased length of the source string than other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what your GetRanges function is trying to do but you definitely do not need loops for this. This function returns the same value as yours when you pass in HasDate as a 1.

```
create function GetRanges
(
    @NumGroups int
) returns table as return

    with MyGroups as
    (
        select NTILE(@NumGroups) over(order by t.id) as GroupNum
            , t.id
        from tempnums t
    )

    select GroupNum
        , MIN(id) as MinNum
        , MAX(id) as MaxNum
    from MyGroups
    group by GroupNum
```

--EDIT--

Now that I see you posted two sets of sample data I understand the problem.

Here is how you can adjust this to accommodate NULL or NOT NULL in somedate.

```
alter function GetRanges
(
    @NumGroups int
    , @HasDate bit
) returns table as return

    with MyGroups as
    (
        select NTILE(@NumGroups) over(order by t.id) as GroupNum
            , t.id
        from tempnums t
        where
        (
            @HasDate = 1
            AND
            t.somedate is not null
        )
        OR
        (
            @HasDate = 0
            AND
            t.somedate is null
        )
    )

    select GroupNum
        , MIN(id) as MinNum
        , MAX(id) as MaxNum
    from MyGroups
    group by GroupNum
```

The issue I see is that you have only 14 rows that have NULL so not sure why your desired output is the way you have it. Using NTILE will produce slightly different results on your sample data because of the way NTILE puts uneven rows into groups.

Comment: GetRanges function is trying to get same number of elements (or as close as possible to the same number) in each range and for each range MIN, MAX numbers. So when date is NULL, and for following ids `6,7,8,150,151,152,153,433,2001,2002,2003,2005,3007,10010`, I need MIN and MAX, of each range. When 4 ranges are requested, Range 1 would be 6,7,8, where 6 is min, 8 is max, Range 2 would be 150,151,152, where 150 is min, 152 is max, Range 3 would be 153,433,2001 where 433 is min, 2001 is max and last Range 4 would be 2002,2003,2005,3007,10010 where 2002 is min and 10010 is max.

Comment: Why 6,7 and 8? 151 - 153? Where do these other numbers come from? From what I can see these are just random numbers with no logic behind them at all. There must be some rule that you haven't share with that.

Comment: Say you have a table in DB, and ID column is identity, but some rows get deleted. My example is arbitrary, but I was trying to create random values to illustrate that. I cannot give example with table names and values in my DB.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any real data. But your example is not something I can code against because the missing data or whatever doesn't make any sense. It is just apparently random numbers. Is this maybe doing a left join to another table and finding those where the joined value is NULL? If that is the case it would be simple to adjust the cte above. But without something to work with I can barely even guess for this piece of the puzzle.

Comment: No join table. I have table that has ID and datetime columns. For some IDs, datetime is NULL and for some it is not. Anyway, I'll think about this a bit and try to adjust my question to make more sense.

Comment: Ahh I gotcha. None of your sample data has null for somedate. Give me a few minutes and I will add some sample data and adjust this function.

Comment: Oh goodness...I just now realized you have the null values in your sample data already. I totally missed it. Sorry for the extra confusion.

Comment: I have updated my answer with your requirements as I understand them.

Comment: Great. I'll check when I get back to desk.